# How do I specify a File manager in Idea running in Openbox in Linux?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I've been developing in Idea on Linux for a little while now and am getting used to it after the initial pain of transitioning from Eclipse.

One of my problems has been how to configure the file manager.  I'm running Openbox on Arch Linux and I can't see an obvious way (despite some extensive Googling) to specify a default file manager and I'm not sure if Idea would use it if I did.

Does anyone know how to specify the file manager in Idea for Openbox on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

1. Click IDE Settings -> External Tools, and then click the Add button.
2. Specify the tool - like in this screenshot:
   http://kobo.github.io/grails-improx/img/idea-external-tools-edit-sh.png

Basically you can specify any external program you want.

The program path should point to the binary file you want to use as a file manager (for example thunar is a great one: /usr/bin/thunar    (you can find the correct path by executing "$which thunar" in a terminal)).

The parameter & working dir should be "$FilePath$" & "$FileDir$ (or you can choose other variables if you prefer different functionality)

Comment: This is almost there - it works well as a way of opening any directory in the project with my file browser (XFE in my case). What I actually need is for XFE to be opened whenever I click "Show in File Manager" in the Idea menus or dialogues.